# How to add all the files in directory in ASP.NET and when i click on the link that file should get download?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html

I wanna to display all the files in a directory in ASP.NET. when i click on the list of files available in that it should get download to local or it should open to view?

How to achieve this ? i got all the files in directory but i don't know to make those files to download?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the file downlodble you have to add for each file an href

eg

```
    foreach(string fileName in Dir)
{

   Response.Write("<a href='"+fileName+"'>file name...</a>");
}
```

ore you have to force download in such way

public static void ForceDownload(this HttpResponse Response, string virtualPath, string fileName)

{
    Response.Clear();

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

Response.WriteFile(virtualPath);

Response.ContentType = "";

Response.End();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to [enable directory browsing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) in IIS.

For whatever reason, directory browsing also displays the `web.config` file for the directory.  The following link discuses how to not show it: http://forums.iis.net/t/1149484.aspx/1